# Trimming a dataframe using index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have this dataframe:

```
Date      |Open     |High|   
2019-04-25| 1.84    |1.89
2019-04-26| 1.79    |1.80
2019-04-29| 1.89    |1.90
2019-04-30| 1.63    |1.64
2019-05-01| 1.59    |1.60
2019-05-02| 1.55    |1.59
```

I want to select the dates from **2019-04-29** to **2019-05-01** and only the values of high, is there a method to do this? I want it either in a dataframe or a list to easily be able to test for a value.

**results req**:

```
[1.90, 1.64, 1.60]
```

**or**

```
Date      |  High
2019-04-29| 1.90
2019-04-30| 1.64
2019-05-01| 1.60
```

Thank you,

R

Method by John does work!
However, if anyone else had index_col='Date' set like I did, another method a friend suggested was to use the pandas .loc.

eg.

a = df.loc['2019-04-29':'2019-05-01',:] #This will give new dataframe from dates given.
close = a['High'] #gives all close values

Answer (score 1):

You should filter the 'Date' column and then select the 'High' values. Try the following code. Remark the Date column must be of the type 'Date' not 'String':

```
a = df[(df['Date']>='2019-04-29') & (df['Date']<='2019-05-01')]
a['High'].values
```

Output:
array([1.9 , 1.64, 1.6 ])

I hope this is what you looking for!

Comment: Hi John, Thank you very much! That did work for me however I had to change a few things in my code. I was wondering if you have another method to fix the issues I ran into. (If not is fine too :) This helped me so much.)
The issue I ran into was when I was reading my file, i had the 'Date' set to being my index, thus the code could not detect the key. I would want it to be so that Date would be my index if possible. I used "pd.readcsv(...., index_col='Date')
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Maybe two things that could help you:

Answer (score 0):

I would not set the index_col to 'Date'. Why would you do that? Maybe two things that could help:

1 rename your column labels by:

```
df.rename(columns={0: "Date", 1: "Open", 2: "High"})
```

2 reset the index of your Data Frame by:

```
df.reset_index
```

Hope this could further help you!